# json_decode as a global variable

Tags: php, json, wordpress, widget

I am trying to make some information widget for the console on client sites (wordpress). The code below works as I need it, perfectly.

```php
$url = 'https://example.site/wp-json/';

function _dashboard_clients_info()
{

    global $url;

    $request = wp_remote_get(esc_url_raw($url));

    if (is_wp_error($request)) {
        return false;
    }

    $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $data = json_decode($html);

    $head = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 2;
    }));

    $posts = $data;

    $foot = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 3;
    }));

    $exclude = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    if (!empty($head->dash_description)) {
        echo wpautop('<div class="dash_head">' . $head->dash_description . '</div>');
        echo $head->html_css_js;
    } else {
    };

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if (!in_array($post->_ID, $exclude)) {
            if (!empty($posts)) {
                echo '<div class="dash_post">';
                echo '<h3 class="dash_title">' . $post->dash_title . '</h3>';
                echo wpautop('<div class="dash_description">' . $post->dash_description . '</div>');
                echo $post->html_css_js;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        } else {
        };
    }

    if (!empty($foot->dash_description)) {
        echo wpautop('<div class="dash_foot">' . $foot->dash_description . '</div>');
        echo $foot->html_css_js;
    } else {
    };
}

function _add_dashboard_clients_widget()
{
    global $url;

    $request = wp_remote_get(esc_url_raw($url));

    if (is_wp_error($request)) {
        return false;
    }

    $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $data = json_decode($html);

    $title = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 1;
    }));

    if (!empty($title->dash_description)) {
        $title = '<div class="dash_title">' . $title->dash_description . '</div>';
    } else {
    };

    add_meta_box('dashboard-clients-info', '' . $title . '', '_dashboard_clients_info', $screen, 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', '_add_dashboard_clients_widget');
```

But I understand that it is not perfect. In particular, I have to include `$url` twice to get the widget title and body.

I would like to make the `$data` variable global in order to get the `$url` once, and then take what me need. I tried it like this, but for some reason it doesn't work, it doesn't return anything.

```php
$url = 'https://example.site/wp-json/';

$request = wp_remote_get(esc_url_raw($url));

if (is_wp_error($request)) {
    return false;
}

$html = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
$data = json_decode($html);

function _dashboard_clients_info()
{

    global $data;

    $head = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 2;
    }));

    $posts = $data;

    $foot = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 3;
    }));

    $exclude = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    if (!empty($head->dash_description)) {
        echo wpautop('<div class="dash_head">' . $head->dash_description . '</div>');
        echo $head->html_css_js;
    } else {
    };

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if (!in_array($post->_ID, $exclude)) {
            if (!empty($posts)) {
                echo '<div class="dash_post">';
                echo '<h3 class="dash_title">' . $post->dash_title . '</h3>';
                echo wpautop('<div class="dash_description">' . $post->dash_description . '</div>');
                echo $post->html_css_js;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        } else {
        };
    }

    if (!empty($foot->dash_description)) {
        echo wpautop('<div class="dash_foot">' . $foot->dash_description . '</div>');
        echo $foot->html_css_js;
    } else {
    };
}

function _add_dashboard_clients_widget()
{
    global $data;

    $title = current(array_filter($data, function ($current) {
        return $current->_ID == 1;
    }));

    if (!empty($title->dash_description)) {
        $title = '<div class="dash_title">' . $title->dash_description . '</div>';
    } else {
    };

    add_meta_box('dashboard-clients-info', 'test', '_dashboard_clients_info', $screen, 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', '_add_dashboard_clients_widget');
```

I will be grateful for any help in improving this. I'm just learning, I try to get knowledge in this way)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily define your API URL in `wp-config.php`, in the theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin's 'root' file (`my-plugin.php` for ex.):

```
define( 'DASHBOARD_API_URL', 'https://example.site/wp-json/' );
```

Then, create a method to receive the dashboard data making use of the defined `DASHBOARD_API_URL`:

```
function wp68412621_get_dashboard_data() {
    $response = wp_remote_get( DASHBOARD_API_URL );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
}
```

You should make use of [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) to cache the API response in order to avoid excessive API calls. Let's adjust the previous method to:

```
function wp68412621_get_dashboard_data() {
    $transient_key = 'dashboard_data';
    $dashboard_data = get_transient( $transient_key );
    
    if ( false === $dashboard_data ) {
        $response = wp_remote_get( DASHBOARD_API_URL );

        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    
        $dashboard_data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        set_transient( $transientKey, $dashboard_data, 900 );
    }
    
    return $dashboard_data;
}
```

Then, you can call the data method from any other method:

```
function wp68412621_dashboard_clients_info()
{
    $data = wp68412621_get_dashboard_data();
    
    if ( empty( $data ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

```
function wp68412621_add_dashboard_clients_widget()
{
    $data = wp68412621_get_dashboard_data();
    
    if ( empty( $data ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // ...
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wp68412621_add_dashboard_clients_widget' );
```